# Accessing Java string array elements into JSP

Tags: java, arrays, string, jsp

I am developing a web application. I have a java class which has array of type String. In the same package, I have .jsp page which handles UI. I want to show contents of java String array into jsp's **select** tag.

```
<select>
   <option>_____</option>
</select>
```

How do I populate this **select** box with Java String array?

Comment: I tried importing that java class into my jsp so that I will be able to access array element. but it is not working

Comment: @Saurabh can you please give some code what you have tried so that we can understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the loop with for-each loop.

With Expression Language,It looks like,

```
   <select name="item">   
       <c:forEach items="${itemsArray}" var="eachItem">   
            <option value="${eachItem}">${eachItem}></option>   
       </c:forEach>   
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<c:foREach>` tag .

```
<select>
   <c:forEach var="option" items="${requestScope.array}">
       <option>${option}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Here is sample [code](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/jsp/jstl-forEach.jspx)

Comment: Ok.. I am seeing an empty select box. In **requestScope.array** do I need to make any changes? Or in **${option}** should I change anything?

Comment: you need to keep the values as request attribute named `array` from your servlet.

Comment: I don't think servlet is interfering here. I have a simple core java class which has String array, the content of which I want to display in jsp select tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL in JSP and the code will be much cleaner:

```
<html:select property="yourPropName">
<html:options name="yourDataList" />
</html:select>
```

Comment: this DataList is nothing but string array elements which I want to show in select

Comment: @Saurabh Deshpande yourDataList is your array string or List<String> from the request or session. It's name of request or session attribute where you put your array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with POJO class. and access it from jsp like below.

```
<select>
<% String[] pojoObj= (String)request.getAttribute("data");
for (String str: pojoObj ){
%>
<option><%=str%></option>
<%}%>
</select>
```

Comment: [Sorry, a big NO to scriplets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files), Recommending scriplets is highly discouraged.

Comment: This link may help you to understand why to avoid scriptlets in jsp . http://thewebplant.com/why-no-scripts-should-be-written-in-jsps-java/

Answer (score -1):

read the elements of the array in a loop and then print it inside the loop

```
<select> 
<%
for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
<option value="<%= arr[i]%>"><%= arr[i]%></option>
} 
%>
</select>
```

Comment: it says arr cannot be resolve. I already imported class in jsp.

Comment: in place of arr u have to write the name of your array object

Comment: @anonymous - I did that.. then itself it is saying cannot resolved